# How to send an array with HttpResponse?

Tags: rust, actix-web

Is there a way to send a vector (array) through a HttpResponse with actix_web?

I can send strings in the body completely fine and was hoping to send an array for the client to receive and store.

This is my currently used code snippet which responds with an error in the .body(data):

```
        let smembers_check = database::smembers(info.key).ok();
        if smembers_check != None
        {
            let data = smembers_check.unwrap();
            HttpResponse::Ok().body(data)
        }
        else
        {
            HttpResponse::Ok().body("")
        }
```

Is there a solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What form do you want to array to take? You could encode the array into a string as JSON, or you could send binary data, but then the client needs to know how to decode that binary data.

Comment: How would I encode the array into a JSON string? Thanks!

Comment: @YunJaeJung You should be able to return a [`Result<actix_web::web::JSON`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.1.0/actix_web/web/struct.Json.html), and return a `Json(thing)` where "thing" is a JSON-convertible structure. So here returning `Ok(Json(data))` should do the trick.

Comment: That aside, you should not check against `None` then unwrap, that's fiddly redundant. Just use `match` or `if let`, or use some of the combinators to process the result into the shape you need e.g. `map`/`and_then`/`unwrap_or`/`ok_or`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return HttpResponse in handler signature and return data like this:  HttpResponse::Ok().json(data)

Comment: Hi this technically works but when I try to access the members of the array clientside it ends up storing each character as an object. E.G. array = ["Dungeons&Dragons", "ModelBuilding", "FlowerArranging"] and array[0] = [, array[1]=", array[2]=D. How do I fix it so there's three objects as originally expressed by the array?

Comment: If the json returned by the handler does not meet your requirement client-side, then you can construct a custom json format with the json! macro in serde_json crate.

Comment: Ahh I was just trying to convert the string that the client receives back into an array. Apparently I can just apply JSON.parse(array).

Answer (score 1):

You can use serde to serialize / deserialize your db model (or any struct you want to return as json) and then you can use .json() on the HttpResponse

example:

```
pub async fn get_all_users(data: Data<AppState>) -> impl Responder {
  let users: Vec<Model> = User::find().all(&data.db).await.unwrap();
  HttpResponse::Ok().json(users)
}
```

On the user struct derive add the serialize / deserialize from serde, here's model example with sea-orm:

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, DeriveEntityModel, Eq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[sea_orm(table_name = "user")]
pub struct Model {
  #[sea_orm(primary_key, auto_increment = false)]
  pub id: Uuid,
  pub email: String,
  pub password: String,
}
```

the same can be applied to any rust struct you want to return as json